# If - then statement in google spreadsheet

Tags: formula, spreadsheet

I have a sheet with a lot of columns that I use as parent feed for my eCommerce shop. It has columns like; `price`, `availability`, `title`, `description`, etc. 
As I need to customize this feed for different services (they ask me less values in a clean sheet). I got some sheets with the columns I need, so I can call them like: `=Sheet1!B2"`

Now, I got to format this data, because for example, in some services, availability should have a value like, "in stock", and in others its just... yes/no.

How can I do something like:

```
IF (Sheet1!B2 == "in stock") then 
   show "yes"
else 
    show no.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear - are you looking for a formula or a script? Do you have an example of your data and the expected output you could show to us?

If you are looking for a formula, this should do the trick:

```
=IF(Sheet1!B2="in stock","yes","no")
```